# How can you check previous yarn ApplicationId?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Let's say I want to check the yarn logs with the command "yarn logs" but I can't access to the ApplicationID of a MapReduce job neither through the output or the spark context of the code. How can I check the last Application ID's that have been executed?

Comment: Actually this is what I was looking for. Spend some time looking for it but I was searching through the yarn logs command. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list of all the applications submitted so far, you can use the following command:

```
yarn application -list -appStates ALL
```

You can also filter the applications, based on the state (possible states: `NEW`, `NEW_SAVING`, `SUBMITTED`, `ACCEPTED`, `RUNNING`, `FINISHED`, `FAILED`and  `KILLED`).

For e.g. to get the list of all the "FAILED" applications, you can execute the following command:

```
yarn application -list -appStates FAILED
```